# jQuery Hover Won't Work in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hover, effect

I have some jQuery I am trying to integrate into my WordPress site. I've been pretty successful so far but there's one specific portion I am having trouble with. Right now my prettyPhoto lightbox works fine, but the hover effect is not happening. I know the coding is sound, based on this example I made here: [Example](http://www.delindesign.com/excellence/wp-content/themes/excellence/videos/index.html)

I believe the problem is the way WordPress reads the jQuery. I looked for some solutions, but I think there could be something in here that's a little out of my experience. My Javascript file can be found here: [ContentHover Plugin](http://www.delindesign.com/excellence/wp-content/themes/excellence/videos/js/content-hover.js). If anyone can point me to a possible solution it would be a huge help. Thanks!

```
/* Hover Effect */
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.d1').contenthover({
    overlay_background:'#00727D',
    overlay_opacity:0.85
    });
})
</script>


/* prettyPhoto */
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not upgrade the Jquery version more than 1.8.3

Comment: Right now I am using a jQuery plugin, included in the post. I am using no higher than 1.7.2 throughout.

Comment: Please list the reason you don't think jquery should be updated past 1.8.3.